# Finding largest value in an array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, io

I'm programming in Java.   I'm not good at programming, but I'm trying.

I managed to create a file that generates an array of  10k random (in range 1 through 1 million) numbers into a text file. This class is called '`CreateDataFile`'

What I'm trying to do now is read the array from the text file created in 'CreateDataFile' from a completely different class.  This new class is called '`ProcessDataFile`'

The first thing I thought about doing is '`extends`' the class.  So both classes communicate.

The thing is, I know how to create a for loop in a program and then find the largest number.  I just don't understand how to read this text file, and create a for loop that processes from the text file and finds the max value.

Here's my `CreateDataFile` class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CreateDataFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] integers = new int[10000];
    Random r = new Random();


    try{

        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("dataset529.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i <integers.length; i++) {
            int number = r.nextInt(1000000)+1;
            p.print(" " + number);

        }


        p.close();

        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    }
```

Now this generates the numbers I need into a text file called dataset529.

If everything was in one class, I'd just create a for loop.. something like

```
int max = integers[0];
for(int i = 0; i<integers.length; i++){
  if (integers[i] > max)
System.out.println(integers[i]);

}
```

But as I'm creating my `ProcessDataFile` class, I'm having a hard time reading the text file created from the CreateDataFile class.

Any ideas on how I can read this text file and run a for loop over it to find the max number like I used above?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should write in the file each number on one line so that it's easier when you read the numbers from the file. This can be done just by doing:

```
p.print(number + "\n");
```

After that, you can use this code to get the max of all the numbers:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ProcessDataFile {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "dataset529.txt";
    String temp;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int i = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[10000];

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        while((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(temp.isEmpty())
                break;
            numbers[i++] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        if(max < numbers[i])
            max = numbers[i];

    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: This may cause a resource leak. You should put your `br.close()` statement in a `finally` block, or ideally, use a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: If you are going to just give a "big chunk of code" to a beginner without explanation, please apply good coding practices, like using try-with-resources, inconsistent exception handling, using `==` to compare strings etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Write the content of each number on new line. While reading the file, maintain a `max` element.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class CreateDataFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] integers = new int[10000];
        Random r = new Random();
        try {
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("dataset529.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
                int number = r.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
                p.print(number + "\n");
            }
            p.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now read the file line by line.

```
public class ProcessDataFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataset529.txt"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (max < num) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: If you like to provide code, then it is always a good idea to make sure, that this code would at least compile :). So hint: please do that.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  I'll try to work off these answers you guys provided.  I did get a NumberFormateException error, tho.  But thanks very much